# Set Image View gravity right Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make the shuffle-button (image view) to the right using gravity
as picture below.

[image]

Here is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:weightSum="2"
       >
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/Loop"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="L"
           android:gravity="left"
           android:textSize="36sp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"
            />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/shuffle"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"
           android:gravity="right"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shuffle_black_24dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

What did I do wrong? I could move the L button fine, but not the shuffle button.

Comment: Wrap textview and imageview in Relativelayout, then set alignParentEnd property to the imageview and alignParentStart property to the textview.

Comment: This is as assignment an unfortunately, I am only allowed to use linear layout :(

Comment: Then increase layout_weight of textview by 0.4 points i.e make it 1.4 and likewise decrease layout_weight of imageview i.e make it 0.6

Comment: Oh ok I get the idea. So it's not possible to use gravity/layout gravity to do this?

Comment: No, because LinearLayout will align its child views in stack horizontally or vertically. So they will be arranged in order i.e one next to another. So you can either use Relative layout or you can manage it by layout weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by:

1. Removing the layout_weight and weightSum from your LinearLayout
2. Changing the width of the ImageView to wrap_content
3. Changing the layout_weight of the ImageView to 0

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Loop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="L"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shuffle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shuffle_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will allow the ImageView to take up as much space as it needs, based on the size of the src asset. The rest of the space will be utilized by the TextView.